# Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом клике мыши не всплывало событие на body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Есть кнопка поиска по которой открывается выпадающая форма с полем поиска и соответственно по клику на произвольной области закрывается. 
А, как сделать так, чтобы при каждом клике мыши не всплывало событие на `body`, но при этом окошко с формой закрывалось, если кликаешь вне области?

```js
$('.js-open-search-panel').on('click', function() {
  $(".search-box").slideDown();
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('js-open-search-panel')) {
    if ($(".search-box").is(":visible")) {
      $(".search-box").slideUp();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  min-height: 68px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

#searchsubmit {
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="top-panel-open-search button js-open-search-panel shown-sm">Поиск</button>
  <div class="search-box">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="">
      <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Найти:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Поиск">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex illo dignissimos, maxime architecto et ab vero hic. Quaerat facere laborum molestias cumque commodi consectetur culpa dolorum praesentium, illo ut assumenda.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для окошка делаете блок-обертку на всю ширину и высоту экрана. Можете воспользоваться `position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`. При открытии окошка, отображаете обертку, при клике на обертку, закрываете окошко и скрываете обертку. Для пользователя это будет незаметно.

Примерно так же работает и модалка в Bootstrap, но там видно обертку (затемнение фона за модалкой)

Answer (score 1):

Подобные вещи уже решены в bootstrap
Посмотри в его сторону, может быть, пригодится

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вопрос вроде не про бутстрап

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.js-open-search-panel').on('click', function() {
  $(".search-box").slideDown();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.closest(".search-box").length == 0) {
    $(".search-box").slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  min-height: 68px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

#searchsubmit {
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="top-panel-open-search button js-open-search-panel shown-sm">Поиск</button>
  <div class="search-box">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="">
      <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Найти:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Поиск">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex illo dignissimos, maxime architecto et ab vero hic. Quaerat facere laborum molestias cumque commodi consectetur culpa dolorum praesentium, illo ut assumenda.</p>
```

Попробуйте так...